# The class AppCompatActivity is a subclass of Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, extends

Hi guys I've a more theorical question.

Is **AppCompatActivity** a subclass of **Activity**?

The AppCompatActivity class is a subclass of the FragmentActivity class directly and the ComponentActivity class indirectly, and these superclasses are subclasses of the Activity.
This makes AppCompatActivity a subclass of the Activity?
[AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjnNu.png)

It is not a subclass directly, but still inherits some constants and fields from the Activity.
[Inherited constants and fields from Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeLBz.png)

This is why I am in doubt, can someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` is a *direct* subclass of `FragmentActivity`, i.e. `FragmentActivity` is its *direct superclass*, the one it `extends`. But `Activity` is still **a** superclass of `AppCompatActivity`, because it appears higher in the inheritance hierarchy, like in the image you posted:

[image: A screenshot of the AppCompatActivity docs, showing the inheritance hierarchy]

Every class has **one** *direct* superclass (single inheritance) - if you don't specify one, the class inherits from `Object`. Everything ultimately inherits from that, which is why every class *is* an `Object`.

When you create a class, you're taking its superclass as a starting point - it *is* that superclass, so you have all the same methods, the same fields, etc. All the stuff you declare in your class is effectively *adding to* that superclass - that's why the keyword is `extends`, right? So all the superclass stuff is included, you can't remove it (beyond using `override` to *replace* the behaviour - and you can still call the original method from the superclass if you want!).

That's the point of inheritance - you take existing structure and functionality, and derive something more specific that makes use of it all. And this applies all the way up the chain - `AppCompatActivity` has everything that `FragmentActivity` has, which includes the stuff that `FragmentActivity` inherits from `ComponentActivity`, and so on. `Object` defines the `toString()` method, which is why *every single class* has that method - they all ultimately inherit from `Object`, but often not directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`

It doesn't matter how many classes come in between a superclass and a subclass... there is still an **"is a"** relationship between them.

> It is not a subclass directly, but still inherits some constants and fields from the Activity. Inherited constants and fields from Activity

can you please specify what field is in the `activity` class and not in the `AppCompatActivity` class?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).